# How print a float variable up to two decimal places in jsp?

Tags: jsp, variables

I need to print a float variable in browser using JSP up to two decimal places.

For example, let's say I have the following variable:

```
float amount=123.2782;
```

I need to print 123.28 on the browser.

Thanks in advance
Mehedi

Answer (score 7):

Add the following line of code on top of your jsp page.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Then use the following line of code to show your digit

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" maxFractionDigits="2" value="${amount}"/>
```

Here `maxFractionDigits` attribute is used to define how many digits you want to show after the decimal point.

Comment: Best answer, however, if OP had `123.2` as decimal, your code would actually print `123.2`. Including `minFractionDigits="2"` would make it print `123.20`.

Answer (score 3):

```
java.util.Formatter formatter = new java.util.Formatter();
formatter.format("%.2f", amount);
```

For more information, consult the documentation of [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class.

You can also use DecimalFormat with slightly different syntax.

Comment: I am working with jsp. As I know printf is not supported by jsp to display in webpage.
thanks

Comment: The `Formatter`’s `format` method returns the formatter itself. You’d need to call `toString` on it, e.g. `new java.util.Formatter().format("%.2f", amount).toString()`, to get the resulting string. On the other hand, you can simply use `String.format("%.2f", amount)` to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

after

```
  add <@page import="java.math.BigDecimal"> to your jsp first

    <%
        BigDecimal bigd=new BigDecimal();
        bigd=bigd.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
        out.println(bigd);
    %>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but it doesn't solve my problem. if I use this code one error occurred. The error is: "cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BigDecimal
  location: class SimplifiedJSPServlet"

Comment: add <%@ page import="java.math.BigDecimal" %> to your jsp first

Comment: scriptlet should not use. It should be use as very worst case